# Как сгруппировать элементы для разных экранов?

Tags: html, css

Как расположить элементы так как показано на схеме?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через `grid` можно (свойство `order`), с учетом медиа-запросов, само собой. С `flex` тоже можно, но с сеткой мудрить надо будет.

```css
.blocks {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.blocks div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  align-items: cetner;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.blocks__block3 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

@media(max-width: 800px) {
  .blocks {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
  .blocks div {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 3;
  }
  
  .blocks__block1 {
    order: 1;
  }
  
  .blocks__block2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  
  .blocks__block3 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="blocks__block1">1</div>
  <div class="blocks__block2">2</div>
  <div class="blocks__block3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если какой-то элемент нужно просто сместить в самое начало или в самый конец, то свойство order можно устанавливать только ему, относительно нуля. Иначе, при добавлении новых элементов можно запутаться с их сортировкой.

Answer (score 2):

И вариант на flex (вдруг понадобится):

```css
.blocks {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.blocks > div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 20px;
}
.blocks__block1,
.blocks__block2 {
  width: 30%;
}
.blocks__block3 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 200px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .blocks__block1 {
    width: 100%;
    order: 1;
  }
  .blocks__block2 {
    width: 100%;
    order: 3;
  }
  .blocks__block3 {
    margin: 20px 0;
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="blocks__block1">1</div>
  <div class="blocks__block2">2</div>
  <div class="blocks__block3">3</div>
</div>
```